# How to join 3 tables with one common column in asp.net-mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in asp.net-mvc5 and I am facing the problem in joining the 3 table with common column name so please would you help me to solve this problem.
this is my index View:

```
<body>
<div>        
<table>
<thead>
<tr>                    
<th>                                                                                 
<center> title                                                           
</center>                                                    
</th>
<th>                                                                                 
<center> description
</center>                                                    
</th>  
<th>                                                                                 
<center> @class
</center>                                                    
</th> 
<th>                                                                                 
<center> subject
</center>                                                    
</th>
<th>                                                                                 
<center> file
</center>                                                    
</th> 
<tbody>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr>
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.title)
 </td>
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.description)
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.@class)
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.subject)
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.file)
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>        
</tr>            
</thead>           
</table>            
</div>
</body>
```

this is my table's:
Table1 name is :
tbl_class:
ClassID
ClassName

Table2 name is :
tbl_subject:
SubjectID
SubjecName

Table3 name is :
tbl_academicsyllabus:
academicSyllabusId
title 
description 
@class
subject
file.

I want to display the class name and subject name in tb_academic syllabus but I am getting the output and it displaying Class-ID and Subject-ID in my table. so how can I display the class-name and subject name instead of displaying the Class-ID and Subject-ID and I want save the Class-ID and Subject-ID instead saving Class-name and Subject-name.so please help me

Comment: Do you really need your Viewbags? I know thats out of the scope for the question. What happens if you change the code in your select new from '@class = b.classID' to '@class = b.className'? Repeat for subject.

Comment: yes I need ViewBags for to display the className and subjectName in dropdwonList @chrillelundmark

Comment: What about the other solution suggestion, did it work? Can you add the view? I want to see how you display the items.

Comment: @chrillelundmark I have posted my Index View code just check it.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Join 3 tables :

```
  var data = from a in db.tbl_academicsyllabus
                   join b in db.tbl_class on a.@class equals b.ClassID 
                   join c in db.tbl_subject on a.subject equals c.SubjectID
                   select new {
                       academicSyllabusId = a.academicSyllabusId,
                       title = a.title,
                       description = a.description,
                       @class = b.className,
                       subject = c.subjectName,
                       file = a.file
                   };
```

Comment: I'm getting the error when I run this code. the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object @Ram Anugandula

Comment: @karthik Object reference not set to an instance that means some of your object is null and you are reading the value from that object. Please debug your code.

Comment: thanks.The error is showing in foreach statement in index view @Ram Anugandula

Comment: which i have just posted My index View just check it once @Ram Anugandula

Comment: @kartick does my linq query answered your question?.

Comment: @kartick where is the foreach statement in your index view?

Comment: just I added my foreach statement to my index view @Ram Anugandula